# c++ , struct, разбитие строки

Tags: c++

здраствуйте форумчане, суть моего вопроса состоит в том что надо разбить строку сисволом '=' из переменой env и записать в структуру block

```
struct block 
{
    char *name;
    char *value;
};

int main(int, char**, char** env)
```

Comment: Именно в `char *`? Взяли бы `std::string`?

Comment: меня интресует самое примитивное что только можно придумать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно изобразить что-то в таком духе:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct block 
{
  char *name;
  char *value;
};

int
main (int ac, char *av[], char **env)
{
  int n = 0;
  while (env[n])
    n++;

  struct block p[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    p[i].name = strdup(env[i]);
    p[i].value = strchr(p[i].name, '=') + 1;
    p[i].value[-1] = 0;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%s : '%s'\n", p[i].name, p[i].value);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Если опасаетесь некорректно сформированного *`env[]`*, добавьте проверку самостоятельно.

Если что-то непонятно, читайте *manpages*, а потом не стесняйтесь, спрашивайте.

Comment: Вот подскажите где сдесь может бить ошибка (Ошибка сегментирования)
`#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

struct block 
{
    char *name;
    char *value;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv, char** env)
{
    FILE *stdout = new FILE;
    stdout = fopen("/dev/stdout", "wr");

    struct block * http;
    block * request = new block;
    
    const char * h = "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
    std::cout << h;

    for (int i=0; env[i]; i++)
    {
        for (int u=0; env[i][u]; u++)
        http[i].name[u] = env[i][u];
    }
    // std::cout << http[0].name; 
}`

Comment: @YuraPlitman,  `struct block * http;` память нигде не выделена. / А зачем так вычурно с `stdout`?

Comment: изучаю механику ввода вивода))

Comment: @YuraPlitman, ОК, страничка грузится быстро -) Успехов!

Comment: вам спасибо, вы даже не подозреваете как помогли (второй день колупаюсь) )))))

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал примерно так:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

struct block
{
    std::string name, value;
};

int main(int, char **, char **env) 
{
    std::vector<block> blocks;

    for (char **ptr = env; *ptr; ptr++)
    {
        std::string_view string = *ptr;
        std::size_t separator = string.find_first_of('=');
        blocks.push_back({std::string(string.substr(0, separator)),
                          std::string(string.substr(separator+1))});
    }

    for (const block &b : blocks)
        std::cout << b.name << " = " << b.value << '\n';
}
```